# jquery .valid() = true before remote validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, asp.net-mvc-5, remote-validation

I am working in `MVC5` and using a combination of client and server validation. For this particular issue I am using remote validation.

The **Razorview**:

```
<div id="studentStatus" name="studentStatus">
@using (Html.BeginForm("StudentStatus", "StudentStatus", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "studentStatusForm", data_timer = 240000 }))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.CurrentStudentSepId, new { @class = "hideMe" })
    <div class="row">
        <h2 class="col-md-12 topSectionHeader">
            @StaffPortalResources.Section_StudentStatus
            <span class="savedStatus"></span>
        </h2>
    </div>
    <span class="errorNotification"></span>
    <div class="questionGroup form-group">
        <div class="row margin-btm-sm">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.StudentStatusId)
                @if (Model.IsReadOnly)
                {
                    <div>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.StudentStatusId)</div>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.StudentStatusId)
                }
                else
                {
                    @Html.CustomComboBoxFor(x => x.StudentStatusId, (new { @class = "statusChangeValidationHandler", data_action = "GetStudentEditableStatuses", data_controller = "Lookup" }))
                }

                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.StudentStatusId)
            </div>
 }
```

The model:

```
public sealed class StudentStatusSectionViewModel : SectionViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Status", ResourceType = typeof(StaffPortalResources))]
    [SelectMustExist(true, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof (StaffPortalResources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "StudentStatus_InvalidSelection")]
    [Remote("ValidateStudentStatus", "StudentStatus", AdditionalFields = "CurrentStudentSepId")]
    public string StudentStatusId { get; set; }

    public bool DoNotReenroll { get; set; }
}
```

The controller:

```
public JsonResult ValidateStudentStatus(StudentStatusSectionViewModel model)
{
    var errors = _studentStatusSectionAdapter.ValidateStudentStatus(model.CurrentStudentSepId, model.StudentStatusId);
    if (errors != null && errors.Any())
    {
        var currentStatus = _studentStatusSectionAdapter.Get(model.CurrentStudentSepId).StudentStatusId;
        Response.AddHeader("status", currentStatus);
        return Json(string.Join("</br>", errors), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The remote validation .complete() function:

```
scope.initializeStudentStatusDropdown = function() {
    var $element = $('#studentStatusForm').find('input.statusChangeValidationHandler[data-role="combobox"]');

    $element.rules().remote.complete = function (xhr) {
        if (xhr.responseText !== 'true')
            window.Registration.StudentStatus.fixStudentStatusDropdown($element, xhr.getResponseHeader);
    }
}

scope.fixStudentStatusDropdown = function($element,responseHeader) {
    $element.kVal(responseHeader('status'));
}
```

The jquery used to wire validation on change event:

```
scope.initializeAutoSave = function (form, callBack) {
    var $form = $(form);
    $form.on("change", "input:not(.ignoreAutoSave)", queueForm);
    $form.on("change", "textarea:not(.ignoreAutoSave)", queueForm);
    window.Validation.initializeValidator($form);
    callBacks[$form.attr('id')] = callBack || function() {};
}
```

The queueForm method:

```
function queueForm(e) {
    if ($(e.target).valid()) {
        var $form = $(e.target).closest("form");
        var timer = $form.data("timer");
        autoSaveQueue[$form.attr("id")] = { $form: $form, timer: timer, attempt: 0 };
    }
}
```

When tracing through the code after changing the value in the dropdown, the change event fires and calls the queueForm function. the `valid()` call evaluates to true before the remote validation happens.

It is not until after I step over 'if `($(e.target).valid())`' line, and it evaluates to true and steps into the if block. Then it jumps into the remote `ValidateStudentStatus` function in my controller.

Have I done something wrong here? Am I misunderstanding how the remote validation works?

Any insight or help would be greatly appreciated!